# Finding Hessian of linear MSE using Index Notatio

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix, index-notation

I am trying to compute the hessian from a linear mse (mean square error) function using the index notation. I would be glad, if you could check my result and tell me if the way that I use the index notation is correct ?

The linear MSE:
$$L(w) = \frac{1}{2N} e^T e$$where $e=(y-Xw)$,

$y \in R^{Nx1} (vector)$

$X \in R^{NxD} (matrix)$

$w \in R^{Dx1} (vector)$

Now the aim is to calculate the Hessin: $\frac{\partial L(w)}{\partial^2 w}$

I proceed as follows:

$\frac{\partial L(w)}{\partial w_i w_j}=\frac{1}{\partial w_i \partial w_j} [\frac{1}{2N}(y_i-x_{ij} w_j)^2]$

$=\frac{1}{\partial w_i}\frac{1}{\partial w_j} [\frac{1}{2N}(y_i-x_{ij} w_j)^2]$

$=\frac{1}{\partial w_i}[\frac{1}{2N}\frac{1}{\partial w_j} (y_i-x_{ij} w_j)^2]$

$=\frac{1}{\partial w_i}[\frac{1}{N}(y_i-x_{ij} w_j)\frac{1}{\partial w_j} (y_i-x_{ij} w_j)]$

$=\frac{1}{\partial w_i}[\frac{1}{N}(y_i-x_{ij} w_j)\frac{-x_{ij} w_j}{\partial w_j}]$

$=\frac{1}{\partial w_i}[\frac{1}{N}(y_i-x_{ij} w_j) (-x_{ij})]$

$=\frac{1}{N}\frac{1}{\partial w_i}[(y_i-x_{ij} w_j) (-x_{ij})]$

$=\frac{1}{N}\frac{-x_{ij} w_j}{\partial w_i}(-x_{ij})]$

$=\frac{1}{N}(-x_{ij}\delta_{ji})(-x_{ij})]$

$=\frac{1}{N}(-x_{ji})(-x_{ij})]$

If I now convert it back to matrix notation the result would be:

$$\frac{\partial L(w)}{\partial^2 w} = \frac{1}{N} X^T X $$

**Is it correct how I used the index notation ?**

Comment: Index notation is more than just the absence of $\Sigma$'s.  Here is the basic rule:  an index which appears once is called a "free index", an index which appears twice is a "dummy index",  and an index which appears thrice is a "mistake".  In your first line, the index $j$ appears three times. In subsequent lines, it occurs up to **five** times.

Comment: @Greg Thank you for your comment. If you have the time, would you mind to show me as an answer how to compute the result, using the index notation correctly ?

Comment: Your final result is correct.  And if you prefix your calculations with $\sum_i\sum_j$, then your derivation is okay. But when you drop the (explicit) summation symbols then you need to follow the rules, i.e. the Einstein summation convention, or no one will understand you.  One last nitpick, the symbol for the partial derivative is $\partial_j$ or $\frac{\partial}{\partial w_j}$ but not $\frac{1}{\partial w_j}$

Comment: @Greg. thank you very much! Could you show me how the third line of my calculation would look like, if I would stick to the Einstein Summation convention ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ease of typing, I'll represent the differential operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial w_k}$ by $d_k$

The known relationships are
$$\eqalign{
 e_i &= X_{ij}w_j - y_i \cr
 d_ke_i &= X_{ij}\,d_kw_j =X_{ij}\,\delta_{jk} = X_{ik} \cr
}$$
Use this to find the derivatives of the objective function
$$\eqalign{
 L &= \frac{1}{2N} e_ie_i \cr
 d_kL &= \frac{1}{N} e_i\,d_ke_i = \frac{1}{N} e_iX_{ik} \cr
 d_md_kL &= \frac{1}{N} X_{ik}\,d_me_i = \frac{1}{N} X_{ik}X_{im}  \cr
\cr
}$$

Comment: how do you know that the answer will be the transpose of x times x by loohing at the indecis ?

Comment: @james If you want to solve problems using index notation, then you must understand basic stuff like $$\eqalign{C&=AB&\implies C_{ik}=A_{ij}B_{jk}\cr Z&=X^TY&\implies Z_{ik}=X_{ji}Y_{jk}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Matrix notations:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial w} (Y - Xw)'(Y-Xw) = 2X'(Y-Xw).
$$
Using indices you are taking derivative of the sum of squares w.r.t. each of the $w_j$, i.e., 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial w_j} ( \sum_{i=1}^N(y_i - \sum_{j=1}^Dx_{ij} w_j))^2= -2 \sum_{i=1}^N(y_i - \sum_{j=1}^Dx_{ij} w_j)x_{ij}.
$$
Back to the matrix notation for the second derivative (the Hessian matrix),
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial w w'} (Y - Xw)'(Y-Xw)  = \frac{\partial}{\partial w'} 2X'(Y-Xw) = 2X'X.
$$
Where using index notations, you are taking derivative w.r.t. to each $w_j$, $j=1,..., D$ , from each of the aforementioned $D$ equations, i.e., 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial w_j^2} ( \sum_{i=1}^N(y_i - \sum_{j=1}^Dx_{ij} w_j))^2 = \frac{\partial}{\partial w_j}(-2 \sum_{i=1}^N(y_i - \sum_{j=1}^Dx_{ij} w_j)x_{ij}) = 2\sum_{i=1}^Nx_{ij}^2,
$$
and for the cross terms,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial w_jw_k} ( \sum_{i=1}^N(y_i - \sum_{j=1}^Dx_{ij} w_j))^2 = \frac{\partial}{\partial w_k}(-2 \sum_{i=1}^N(y_i - \sum_{j=1}^Dx_{ij} w_j)x_{ij}) = 2\sum_{i=1}^Nx_{ij}x_{ik}.
$$
Where the last expression is the $jk$-th (and the $kj$-th) entry of $2X'X$ such that $j\neq k$. And the equation before represents the entries on the main diagonal of $2X'X$.